# Getting "A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute" in my ios application while trying to sign up user through AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am getting "A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute" when I try to sign up a user into my ios application (using swift) using Amazon Cognito.

[Here is a screen shot of my user pool settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6HzT.png)

Please suggest me a work around for it.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to set up an attribute (if you only showed the code), but you do not have permissions for that. In this case, go to "App clients" section, find your ios app client and add needed attributes. In screens:

1. [image: App clients section]
2. [image: Attributes permissions section]